# Expression> is not working as expected in mock setup xunit .net6

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, xunit

I try to test this method using xunit .

```
public async Task<IList<DraftEntity>> Handle(GetDraftsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var res = await _repository.GetAllAsync(a => a.CustomerIsin == _user.CustomerIsin);
    return res.Data;
}
```

Here is my test code :

```
  public async void GetDraftsQueryTest_when_customerISIN_is_same_draft_is_not_null()
    {
        //Arange

        IList<DraftEntity> ListOutpuddata = new List<DraftEntity>() { new DraftEntity()
        {
            CustomerIsin=customerisin,

        }

        };
       
        repo.Setup(i => i.GetAllAsync(i=>i.CustomerIsin==It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(OperationResult<IList<DraftEntity>>.Succeed(ListOutpuddata)));

     }
```

But when I debug the code the `res` variable in my method is null .Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final setup

```
  repo.Setup(i => i.GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DraftEntity, bool>>>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(OperationResult<IList<DraftEntity>>.Succeed(ListOutpuddata)));
```